# Adding dates to fanchart plots in R-package `vars`

Tags: r, plot

The R package `vars` has some nice canned routines for `VAR` type modelling, including a very neat fanchart plot method.

The plots do not include dates - the x-axis is just labelled with numbers.

For example:

```
require(vars)
data(Canada)
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
var.2c.prd <- predict(var.2c, n.ahead = 8, ci = 0.95)
fanchart(var.2c.prd)
```

I have looked at the code for `fanchart` but have been unable to understand how I might achieve my objective.

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's base graphics so `xaxt="n"` will suppress the default axis and `axis` can be used to make the new labels. That's a time series object, so it really does not have things we would recognize as dates, but it is possible to pull out the times

```
 times <- as.vector(time(Canada) )
```

This is the code in fanchart that sets up the user-coordinates:

```
plot.ts(c(endog[, names[i]], rep(NA, n.ahead)), main = main[i], 
          ylim = c(ymin, ymax), ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab, col = col.y,  
         ...)
```

I'm trying to add an xy.labels argument so that plot.ts will honor it, so far without success.

<s>I'm going to throw it back to you. This is what I think should give a proper placement, but it is wider than the plotted points. If that makes sense in terms of run-in and runout issues relating to these models, great. if not maybe you can improve on this</s>

```
axis(1, at=seq_along( c( times, rep(NA,8) )), labels=c( times, rep(NA,8)) ,
        las=3, line=2, cex.axis=0.6)
```

The additional NA's are designed to account for the regions with projections. The length comes from `nrow(var.2c.prd$fcst[[1]])
[1] 8`

Hah ... I've got it: Try this

```
fanchart(var.2c.prd, xaxt="n")
 par(new=TRUE)
 axis(1, at=seq_along( c( times, rep(NA,8) )), labels=c( times, rep(NA,8)) ,
       las=3, line=-26, cex.axis=0.6)
 axis(1, at=seq_along( c( times, rep(NA,8) )), labels=c( times, rep(NA,8)) ,
       las=3, line=0.5, cex.axis=0.6)
```

[image]

It didn't seem to be lining up without the `par(new=TRUE)`. You should be able to palce additional axes where you want them.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I'm unsure what's going on, but my cut-and-paste of your code attaches only the first date to the rightmost side of each plot. I'm running R 2.15.1 on a windows box. unable to upgrade as it's a work PC.

Comment: Well a) I think that is a recent enough version, and b) when I restarted d loaded a few packages like `rms`, `zoo`, and `lattice` and their dependencies, I now get the same result as you. I had quite a few packages on board when I got that success so it may have been a side-effect of another package. Will investigate.

Comment: Furthermore, I think those labels are incorrectly placed. The dates should end before the predictions.

Comment: thanks for trying. I am not sure what is going wrong, but i still have the problem that it only attaches a singe date marker to the rightmost point.

Comment: I no longer get that result either, but instead get an axis that is fairly centered although offset to the right a bit, and with four points 1980-1980.75 spread across the panels. Too bad you didn't reply yesterday, I would have had the console session to refer to.